# Python: show all html in html.fromstring

Tags: python, html

I have been scraping a website that requires login and its not getting all the information to require. So I thought it would be best to go back to the start and show all the html it has pulled from the page

how could i do this? below is my initial idea but what am i missing to allow me to debug?

```
browser.get('http://www.racingpost.com' + link)
            tree = html.fromstring(browser.page_source)
            print(tree)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can print out the `browser.page_source` once again:

```
print(browser.page_source)
```

If the browser was closed after getting the `.page_source`, you can remember it into a variable and print it out later:

```
browser.get('http://www.racingpost.com' + link)
# ...
source = browser.page_source
browser.close()

print(source)
```

Or, you can dump the tree back to string via `.tostring()`:

```
print(html.tostring(tree))
```

It also has the pretty-printing implemented:

```
print(html.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```